# Find Characters in a column and then copy entire row to a different spreadsheet

Tags: java

I'd working on drive with google sheets and google forms.
I am adding data to the sheet automatically from the responses of the form.
I don't have much knowledge in script editor or script writing,
but can we search for specific words in a column and then copy the entire row to a new tab or spreadsheet. 
For example, I have Apple, Banana, Mango listed in column and I have three different spreadsheets apart from the main sheet. Where I'd like to add all the cells in row of Apple in one sheet, and Banana in next one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need code.  Just use filter function.

```
=filter(Data!A:A,Main!A:A="Apple")
```

Put this on the "Apple" in column, row where you want data to be filled in assuming your list of items is in Column A of sheet named "Data" in same google sheet.